# Izpack error on installer: could not load COIOSHelper.dll

Tags: java, xml, dll, izpack

Izpack could not load COIOSHelper.dll when trying to install app, this causes the installer to return null before it can finish and though cutting the installation.
I have done a thorough research to resolve this problem and i could find its a window specific problem

I am using windows 8 and the install.jar seem to miss the COIOSHelper.dll file. Am using izpack 5.1.3 and i know its suppose to come with the 3rd party files but in this case its missing and i cant find a website i can download just the **COIOSHelper.dll** file.

**My native code in the Install.xml is as below**

```
<!-- The native libraries to add. This is required for creating shortcuts on Windows -->
    <native type="izpack" name="ShellLink.dll"/>
    <native type="izpack" name="ShellLink_x64.dll"/>
    <native type="3rdparty" name="COIOSHelper.dll" stage="both">
      <os family="windows"/>
    </native>
    <native type="3rdparty" name="COIOSHelper_x64.dll" stage="both">
      <os family="windows"/>
    </native>
```

yet am still getting the COIOSHelper.dll file cant be loaded in all my install.jar. Please i need assistance with this, i dont know what am doing wrong or what i dont know now, if you have encountered same problem your opinion could be well accepted by me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After you define  tag on your `install.xml`
Logically you need to load the native files defined on some folder that will be used by IzPack to run with.
Therefore you can include the `<tempdir/>` tag on your `<info>`
Below are my sample install.xml

```xml
<info>
   <appname>Some Application</appname>
   <appversion>1.0</appversion>
   <appsubpath>Well Some Application</appsubpath>
   <javaversion>1.8</javaversion>
   <requiresjdk>no</requiresjdk>
   <run-privileged/>
   <tempdir/>
</info>
```